# What are the exact dimensions of Silverstone?

Tags: formula-1, venues

I'm trying to create a model of Silverstone and need the exact dimensions of the track. I need the lengths of everything and the angles and sizes of every corner. Does anybody know where this can be found?

I have tried using Google Maps and measuring the distances using the measure tool, however my measurements are always out by a bit. I want to know if there is any website or if anyone knows all the dimensions for the track.

Comment: Is there anywhere else I could ask this question that's more active?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific place that is likely to provide you an answer any quicker than here. If nobody had the information or nobody wants to give it, there's not much else that can be done.